# Create multi-user database schema with roles, permissions, and services

Tags: sql-server, database-design, permissions, users, role

I am in the process of designing a user administration database and I am stuck in the creation of the tables and their relationships, in order to explain myself below I expose the requirements of the schema:

1. Within the schema there must be a table called "Accounts", this table can have one or many "Users".
2. A "User" can only belong to a single "Account".
3. For each account there must be a "root user" who is capable of reading, editing, creating and deleting users but can only do that in the context of that "account".
4. "Globally" there are a series of "services", an account may have enabled the use of one or more of these services.
5. The permissions will be created based on the different services that exist in the application, that is, if for example I have a service called "alerts", there will be the "create alerts", "edit alerts", "delete alerts" permissions. , "see alerts".
6. An account must have permissions and roles for the different services that exist within the application.
7. The "root user" of the "account" can create, edit, view, and delete roles for users within the context of the "account" itself.
8. Within the application there is a "master account" and a "master user", who have all the permissions on all accounts, users, permissions and roles.
9. The "master account" will register services, roles and permissions as new features of the solution are generated in global tables (that is an idea that I currently have but I do not know if it is the correct thing to do)

10.When an "Account" is created, it will be assigned a series of services, permissions and roles. The set of permissions and roles can vary between accounts, since some accounts will have more permissions than others, this will depend on the amount of services they have.

11.The operation of point 10 will be carried out by the "master user" of the application.

I currently have the following scheme:

[image: User Schema With Roles and permissions]

This scheme already includes the roles and permissions but it does so per user, and does not have the characteristic of assigning permissions, services and roles to an "Account". There is also the issue of Global tables for permissions, roles, and services (these are not in the diagram since I do not know if it is correct to do it that way).

Currently this scheme allows the "master user" to create as many accounts as the "account users" but it does not allow the "account root user" to create users or assign roles or permissions to them.

I would like to know what are the objects that I am missing along with their relationships to be able to achieve all that is stated in the previous 11 points and also to know if there is something left over in the diagram, and so on.